# R studio doesn't recognize language

Tags: sql, rstudio, scripting-language

I'm trying to create a data frame from SQL query. 
Some of the fields are become gibberish since they're not in english.
Any solution of how to fix this?

Comment: This question in its current form is not answerable.  Please include the relevant R/SQL code in your question.

Comment: Install language Packages